# Can I combine two scripts into one button in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two buttons on a Google sheet, each running a different script.  I'd like to be able to click one button and have both scripts run.  Is this possible?

My first button/script clears multiple ranges:

```
{function clearRange() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Pricing 
Comparison');
sheet.getRange('B2:B5').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('B7:B12').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('B14:B16').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('B23').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('B26').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('B28:B29').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('E2:E20').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('H13').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('J13').clearContent();

}}

}}
```

My second button/script reverts a cell back to a specific value:

```
function doTest() 
{SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A19').setValue('Multi-tenant 
Cloud');
}
```

I'd love for both of these functions to execute when clicking one button.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could copy-paste the code into a new button, but I doubt that's what you really want.

Comment: Yes.  See answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Use a third function() Like this:

```
function combine() {
  clearRange();//you can change the order if required and add as many as you wish
  doTest();
}
```

Attach combine to your button.

Comment: Thank you.  Sorry, I'm not a developer at all so I'm struggling a little.  So I create a third project "Combine" and put this function in there? Or do I need to add the other functions underneath the combine function that you provided?  If you could copy and paste the exact script that I need to create, I'd be very appreciative.

Comment: I think I did.  You have a function named doTest() and a function named clearRange().  They're both in combine.  So connect your button to combine.  Just copy and paste the combine function.  I noticed you said project.  I assumed that these functions are all in the same project.  Is that true?

Comment: Ahh, that's where I probably have it messed up.  I have them all in different projects. Okay, I put them all in the same project and pointed the button to combine and it worked!  Thanks a ton.  This saved me hours of work.

Comment: Put them all in the same project and make sure that they have `function name(){}` wrappers.